# Reusing structs in loop (in C)

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to insert data into a `Data` struct first, then parse it to an `insertFirst` function that can put it into my linked list. This is all done in a while loop.

```
while(fgets(line, 8, file) != NULL)
{
    x= (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data)); 
    sscanf(line, "%s %s", line, val);

    x->c = line; 
    x->v =val; 

    insertFirst(list, x);
}
```

However I'm trying to reuse the `Data` struct. Mallocing it every time. The problem I have is that despite the lines being read in correctly. 
e.g. `LOREM 1` and `IPSUM 3`, the linked list will always contain `IPSUM 3`. How do i use a struct like this repeatedly in the loop?

Comment: How is `val` declared?

Comment: you're not reusing the struct. You're just assigning pointers pointing to the *same* character array all over. Consider having `command` and `val` as *array members* in the `Data` and `sscanf`ing directly to these instead.

Comment: Also [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Also, `sscanf` can fail

Comment: What is `Data`?

Comment: Data is a struct that holds the two strings called `command` and `value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you are assigning `cmd` and `val` as pointers to `x->command` and `x->value`, hence `x->command` and `x->value` will always points to updated value in `cmd` and `val`.

So you change the code as below.

```
while(fgets(line, 15, inputFile) != NULL)
{
    x= malloc(sizeof(Data)); 
    sscanf(line, "%s %s", cmd, val);

    x->command = strdup(cmd); 
    x->value = strdup(val); 

    insertFirst(list, x);
}
```

Where `strdup` calculates the space needed and allocates the memory dynamically and copies the input string and returns the newly allocated pointer.

Comment: Thank you! Saw what I was doing wrong, needed to allocate memory for command and value. And your use of strdup was more better than my extra mallocs.

Comment: @KevinLe `strdup` does internally the same thing.

Comment: Was just neater than what i had.

Comment: @KevinLe Yes for sure.

Comment: @Kevin Please note though that strdup is not standard C, so it isn't portable.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is this:

```
typedef struct Data
{
    char command[100]; 
    char value[100]; 
} Data; 

while(fgets(line, 15, inputFile) != NULL)
{
    x= (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data)); 
    sscanf(line, "%s %s", x->command, x->value);  

    insertFirst(list, x);
}
```

Disclaimer: no erro checking or bounds checking for the strings is done here for brevity.